# Javascript add data in multidimesional array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, addition

I'm trying to understand how to add a value into my array. It is multidimensional:

```
var eventcontent = {
                '2015-05-02' : [{'title':'somethingtitle1','content':'somethingcontent1','something':'something1'},{'title':'somethingtitle2','content':'somethingcontent2','something':'something2'}],
                '2015-05-07' : [{'title':'somethingtitle7','content':'somethingcontent7','something':'something7'}],
        }
```

How can I achieve adding the following data into the '2015-05-02'?

{'title':'somethingtitle3','content':'somethingcontent3','something':'something3'}

thanks for your help

Comment: `eventcontent['2015-05-02'].push({...})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`eventcontent` is object. Firstly you have to gain access to array stored under `2015-05-02` key. `2015-05-02` is not valid property identifier so you can't access it via

```
var array = eventcontent.2015-05-02 // SyntaxError
```

instead you have to use bracket notation

```
var array = eventcontent['2015-05-02'];
```

then you can for example [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) your data to the array

```
var data = {'title':'somethingtitle3','content':'somethingcontent3','something':'something3'};
var array = eventcontent['2015-05-02'];
array.push(data);
```

## Edit:

Probably you should also check if array actually exist so your code becomes:

```
var data = {'title':'somethingtitle3','content':'somethingcontent3','something':'something3'};
var array = eventcontent['2015-05-02'];

if (array === undefined) // check if it is undefined and if so...
  array = eventcontent['2015-05-02'] = []; // make empty array and assign it to eventcontent under '2015-05-02' key
}

array.push(data);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I always get an error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

here's my declaration:
    var eventcontent = {}

I tried with [] as well.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed that you had `eventcontent` initialized with data. In this case you have to check if the array actually exists and create it if needed.

Comment: It was at first. It give me the same error message. Any idea what it could be.

What I had is in my post above